# Is my configuration file struts.xml correct?

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, struts-action, struts2-interceptors

I want to know  this file is it correct, because I didn't understand interceptor very well.

**struts.xml:**

```
<struts>
    <interceptors>
 <interceptor-stack name="storeStack"> 
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="store"> 
        <param name="operationMode">STORE</param> 
    </interceptor-ref> 
</interceptor-stack>
            <interceptor-stack name="retrieveStack"> 
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/> 
                <interceptor-ref name="store">   
                </interceptor-ref> 
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <action name="index">
            <result>/JSPs/eleve/view.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="ajoutereleves" class="com.injaz.struts2.actions.NavigateAction" method="navigateToAjouterEleveJsp">
            <result name="ajoutereleves">/JSPs/eleve/addeleve.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="listereleves" class="com.injaz.struts2.actions.NavigateAction" method="navigateToListerElevesJsp">
            <result name="listereleves">/JSPs/eleve/showseleves.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="manageeleves" class="com.injaz.struts2.actions.NavigateAction" method="navigateToUpdateElevesJsp">
            <result name="manageeleves">/JSPs/eleve/manageeleves.jsp</result>
        </action>
         <action name="ajoutereleverecord" class="com.injaz.struts2.actions.AddEleveAction" method="execute">
                  
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/> 
                <interceptor-ref name="store"/>  
            <result name="success">/JSPs/eleve/addeleve.jsp</result>        
            <result name="error">/JSPs/eleve/addeleve.jsp</result>
        </action>
         <action name="updateeleve" class="com.injaz.struts2.actions.UpdateEleveAction" method="execute"> 
            <result type="json">
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            </result>
        </action>
         <action name="getupdateeleve" class="com.injaz.struts2.actions.EditEleveAction" method="getEleveObject">
            <interceptor-ref name="storeStack" /> 
            <result name="success">/JSPs/eleve/editeleve.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/JSPs/eleve/editeleve.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="eleveTable" method="getEleveTable" 
                class="com.injaz.struts2.actions.EleveJsonTable">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            </result>
        </action>       
        <action name="validateEleve" class="com.injaz.struts2.validator.EleveValidator" method="validateEleveNom">
        <result type="json">
        <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        </result>
        </action>   
    </package>
</struts>
```

I am using Struts 2.3.1 for more details.

Comment: Does spell-check help count? "Please" have 6 letters, not 3... and not really needed in the questions (reasonably complete sample and detailed error shows more effort than misspelled ask for help). I.e. your XML does not look valid at all in the question.

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov I edited my file,please chek another time because validation don't work for me,message error don't show up,that my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your `struts.xml` is incorrect. Interceptors are invoked before the action execution. It's like a pipeline that serves the request. Each of them invoked one after another. When the last interceptor processed the action is executed. What interceptors to invoke configured in the action configuration or via annotations. For detail explanation of interceptors see [docs](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/interceptors).

The important thing is the order the interceptors are invoked on  the stack. There's a `defaultStack` where the interceptors are collected and ordered appropriately. If you add a reference of the custom interceptor to the stack or action it should comply the order it placed.

The xml configuration file should comply the DTD.